# Azure DevOps hide developers list to stakeholders

Tags: azure-devops

I'd like to avoid for the stakeholders to view the name of developers working on tasks (Assigned To columns).

Is there a way to hide it?

Comment: No. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @DanielMann Because Stakeholders should not view who is working on their projects, the number of people currently assigned, privacy reason, etc...

Comment: Why not? What is your specific concern?

Comment: They ask for more people even if the project needs less, or they try to contact directly the developer, and several others...

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Thanks for your interest, actually I haven't solved my issue, I'll try some workaround or develop by myself an additional interface only for stakeholder. Do you have a plan to develop more configuration on stakeholder UIs?

Comment: This needs waiting further release of the product group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a permission model for fields in a Process Template, so it isn't possible to hide the field only for certain users.

There are a few places in the user-interface where you can customize the view. For example, you can customize the settings for the Kanban Board to pick and choose which fields are displayed:

[image]

And while you can remove Columns from lists, this is only a band-aid workaround as the information is still available and columns can easily be added back in for personal views.

In an agile world, we want our stakeholders to have visibility. Microsoft's view of DevOps is "people and process working with tools to deliver value to customers". Stakeholders have a role in your project, but their contributions aren't the same as those that are doing the work. The classic example is [*Ham and Eggs*](https://www.implementingscrum.com/2006/09/11/the-classic-story-of-the-pig-and-chicken/)

[image]

If your concerns are truly about privacy - **don't give Stakeholders access!** Consider finding an alternate method of keeping them in the loop. For example, Azure DevOps allows you to query their system [via an Excel Plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops).